# jaxb marshalling skip empty elements

Tags: java, jaxb

Using JAXB  is it possible to ensure that null values are not marshalled as () empty elements. For instance

```
public class Contacts {
    @XmlElement(name = "Phone")
    protected List<Phone> phone;
    }
```

currently if one of the phone element is null i get

```
<contact>
         </phone>
         <phone>
                <areacode>919</areacode>
                <phonenumber>6785432</phonenumber>
         </phone>
    </contact>
```

**i want the following output**

```
<contact>
            <phone>
                   <areacode>919</areacode>
                   <phonenumber>6785432</phonenumber>
            </phone>
   </contact>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Null values are not marshaled as empty element by default**.
Only empty values are marshalled as empty element

In your example you are using collection with empty `Phone object` element. You have two elements in list: `empty Phone` (all fields are `null`) and `Phone object` with not null fields.
So,

```
public class Contacts {
    @XmlElement(name = "Phone")
    protected List<Phone> phone = Arrays.asList(new Phone[]{null, null, null});
}
```

will be marshalled to

```xml
<contact/>
```

but

```
public class Contacts {
    @XmlElement(name = "Phone")
    protected List<Phone> phone = Arrays.asList(new Phone[]{new Phone(), new Phone(), null});
}
```

will be marshalled to

```xml
<contact>   
    <Phone/>  
    <Phone/>  
</contact>
```